# Unable to parse json with NULL values

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-api-manager

**(WSO2 API MANAGER v1.9)**

I'm trying to transform back-end service response using script mediator in the out sequence of the API configuration.
    Please find below the sample script mediator code:

```
<script language="js">
     var data = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload"); 
     var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
     mc.setPayloadJSON( jsonData);
</script>
```

I'm getting an error during parsing the JSON request since request contains a null value.
    Could you please suggest how to fix this issue in wso2 API manager v1.9?

Comment: Can you post the error here?

Answer (score 0):

According to your script mediator code, JSON.parse(data) will throw an error if data is not a valid JSON string. You can see that error in carbon logs too. That is what happen when your request have null JSON string. So can modify your code as follows to eliminate the issue.

```
<script language="js">
     var data = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload");
     var jsonData; 
     if (data) {
         try {
             jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
         } catch(e) {
             jsonData = {};
         }
     }
     mc.setPayloadJSON(jsonData);
</script>
```